# Get Timeline from Twitter List

Tags: python, twitterapi-python

I'm trying to get status updates from a list in Twitter, then open in a CSV file, but I keep getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'Status' object has no attribute 'screen_name'.

Any suggestions?

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import csv
import pandas as pd

consumer_key = 'x'
consumer_secret = 'x'
access_token = 'x'
access_secret = 'x'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

f = csv.writer(open('TodaysNews.csv', 'w'))

f.writerow(["screenName", "name", "text", "followers_count", "listed_count", "statuses_count"])

number_of_tweets = 100

tweets_for_csv = []

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_timeline, 'darrenmeritz', 'News',
    twtHandle = tweet.screen_name,
    name = tweet.name,
    text = tweet.text,
    followers_count = tweet.followers_count,
    listed_count = tweet.listed_count,
    statuses_count = tweet.statuses_count,
    result_type='recent',
    include_entities=True,
    trim_user=True,
    truncated=False,
    lang='en').items(number_of_tweets):
    try:
        f.writerow([twtHandle, name, text, followers_count, listed_count, statuses_count])
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        pass
```

Comment: Why did you expect that it has such an attribute?

Comment: The docs for tweepy http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html says the attribute is owner_screen_name for the API call list_timeline